# Haskell parsec token typing condition

Tags: haskell, parsec

Consider the minimized code:

```
module Parser where

import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Pos

oneTokenP f = token show (\_ -> initialPos "Dummy") f
oneToken t = token show (\_ -> initialPos (show t)) 
                  (\t' -> if t == t' then Just () else Nothing)
```

I get error:

```
Parser.hs:8:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream
                             s Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a1
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        oneTokenP :: forall u s a a1.
                     (Show a1,
                      Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream s Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a1) =>
                     (a1 -> Maybe a) -> Text.Parsec.Prim.Parsec s u a

Parser.hs:9:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream
                             s Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        oneToken :: forall u s a.
                    (Eq a, Show a,
                     Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream s Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a) =>
                    a -> Text.Parsec.Prim.Parsec s u ()
```

Which typing condition am I violating?

**Rewritten following @amalloy advice:**

```
oneTokenP f = token showTok posFromTok testTok
 where
     showTok (pos,t) = show t
     posFromTok (pos,t) = initialPos "Dummy"
     testTok (pos,t) = f t
oneToken x = token showTok posFromTok testTok
 where 
     showTok (pos,t) = show t
     posFromTok (pos,t) = initialPos (show t)
     testTok (pos,t) = if x == t then Just () else Nothing
```

Comment: The parser has a `Stream s Identity a` constraint in its inferred type. Because `Identity` is a concrete type, not a type variable, this is not Haskell98, which requires constraints to be of the form `Class var1 … varn`. To allow this, you can just turn on the `FlexibleContexts` extension with a `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` pragma or `-XFlexibleContexts` flag; this and `FlexibleInstances` (which allows the same thing in `instance` definitions) are quite benign extensions and very commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your functions to [the example in the documentation for `token`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Prim.html#v:token):

```
 mytoken x
   = token showTok posFromTok testTok
   where
     showTok (pos,t)     = show t
     posFromTok (pos,t)  = pos
     testTok (pos,t)     = if x == t then Just t else Nothing
```

In each, the input is a tuple of position and token. You are trying to treat such a tuple as if it were just a token. It's not obvious to me why this mistake produces the particular error you get, but I think you can see nonetheless that it is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests

```
(Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
```

So, we can add

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
```

at the top of the file. After that, it compiles fine.